# What characters should be escaped in canonical url's?

Tags: canonical-url, technical-seo, url-encoding

Should I url-encode non-ascii characters in canonical url's?

That is, should i use

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/öland">
```

...or

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/%C3%B6land">
```

I see both being used in the wild, so I wonder if there are any best-practices here.

Comment: It doesn not matter where the link appears. All URLs should be properly encoded, so the second form is the right one per the IRI standard.